# Create a new array using another array in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have array of categories like this and I want to merge the same value like 1 and 0 index value etc in another new array how it is possible.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29
            [parentId] => 0
            [serviceName] => Hair
            [parentServiceImg] => 7ffb7f5aa2a210ba927e9de64ef17f93.jpeg
            [subCategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 30
                    [parentId] => 29
                    [serviceName] => Blow Out
                    [subCategory] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 31
                            [parentId] => 30
                            [serviceName] => Add Clients Hair Extensions & Style
                            [subCategory] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 49
                                    [parentId] => 31
                                    [serviceName] => Hair style color
                                    [servicePrice] => 100
                                )
```

`)

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [parentId] => 0
        [serviceName] => Makeup
        [parentServiceImg] => e00d3576847fef9f717d1de2647ed954.jpeg
        [subCategory] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [parentId] => 1
                [serviceName] => Special Event Makeup
                [subCategory] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [parentId] => 2
                        [serviceName] => Add Airbrush
                        [servicePrice] => 232
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [parentId] => 0
        [serviceName] => Makeup
        [parentServiceImg] => e00d3576847fef9f717d1de2647ed954.jpeg
        [subCategory] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [parentId] => 1
                [serviceName] => Photoshot Makeup
                [subCategory] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 7
                        [parentId] => 6
                        [serviceName] => Add Airbrush
                        [servicePrice] => 8
                    )

            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [parentId] => 0
        [serviceName] => Makeup
        [parentServiceImg] => e00d3576847fef9f717d1de2647ed954.jpeg
        [subCategory] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [parentId] => 1
                [serviceName] => Special Event Makeup
                [subCategory] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [parentId] => 2
                        [serviceName] => Add Lashes
                        [servicePrice] => 6
                    )

            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 29
        [parentId] => 0
        [serviceName] => Hair
        [parentServiceImg] => 7ffb7f5aa2a210ba927e9de64ef17f93.jpeg
        [subCategory] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [parentId] => 1
                [serviceName] => Special Event Makeup
                [subCategory] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 47
                        [parentId] => 29
                        [serviceName] => Wedding Day Mother of the Bride / Mother of the Groom Hair Touch Ups
                        [servicePrice] => 5
                    )

            )

    )
)`

I want to 0 index value merge with 4 index value and get on 0 index of new array  and 1 to 3 index value merge and get on 1 index in new array using php. I need help for this. thanks.

Comment: You had better show us an example of what you want the resulting array to look like.

Comment: And also some code to show what you have treid to do for yourself

Comment: I want in new array like this

Comment: ok I try to explain what i want , In my first array on 0 index and 4 index service name Hair and subCategory are different so i want to merge these subCategory array within one on 0 index in new array like  Hair->subCategory->array('0'=>array('id'=>30),'1'=>array('id'=>2))  like this. thanks

Comment: If you want help it is available in abundance here. But you have to describe what is required. People _should not write code for you_ But they are very unlikely to do that if thay have to **guess** what you want and the criteria that should be used to get from start to result

Comment: ok , @RiggsFolly i agree with you , but in my question I have a array of sub category within a sub category within a sub category and within a main category, I just want to merge same sub category data.

Answer (score 0):

It should help you:

```
<?php
$your_array  = [0=>['array1'], 1=>['array2'],2=>['array3'], 3=>['array4'], 4=>['array5']];
$new_array   = [];
$first       = array_shift($your_array);
$last        = array_pop($your_array);
$array       = array_merge($first, $last);
$new_array[] = $array;
$new_array[] = $your_array;
?>
```

Comment: thanks, @Rayann Nayran I will try this way I hope this resolve my problem. :)